# layoutparser has no attribute Detectron2LayoutModel

Tags: python

Im working on a projet where I need to extract informations from resume in pdf format, the problem is when I use libraries like pdfminer ect sometimes the text extracted is not the good result because it gets lines overlapped with other lines from another box of text, thats why I thought of using layout parser first before extracting the text to extract text based on boxes of text

```
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd ="C/Users/faty/Downloads/tesseract-ocr-w64-setup-v5.1.0.20220510.exe"
poppler_path="C:/Users/faty/Downloads/Release-22.04.0-0/poppler-22.04.0/Library/bin"



model = lp.Detectron2LayoutModel('lp://PubLayNet/mask_rcnn_X_101_32x8d_FPN_3x/config',
                                 extra_config=["MODEL.ROI_HEADS.SCORE_THRESH_TEST", 0.5],
                                 label_map={0: "Text", 1: "Title", 2: "List", 
                                 3:"Table",4:"Figure"})

layout_result = model.detect(img)

lp.draw_box(img, layout_result,  box_width=5, box_alpha=0.2, show_element_type=True)
```

I Get this error :
AttributeError: module layoutparser has no attribute Detectron2LayoutModel

Answer (score 9):

Actually the attribute `Detectron2LayoutModel` can be accessed only inside `models`:

```
model = lp.models.Detectron2LayoutModel('lp://PubLayNet/mask_rcnn_X_101_32x8d_FPN_3x/config',
                                 extra_config=["MODEL.ROI_HEADS.SCORE_THRESH_TEST", 0.5],
                                 label_map={0: "Text", 1: "Title", 2: "List", 
                                 3:"Table",4:"Figure"})
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to first install pycocotools and then Detectron2. Detectron2 do not have support on windows. Follow official installation guide mentioned below

[layout-parser installation guide](https://github.com/Layout-Parser/layout-parser/blob/main/installation.md)

In this guide there is a link to install pycocotools and [Detectron2](https://ivanpp.cc/detectron2-walkthrough-windows/#step3installdetectron2)

Use below command to install Detectron2

pip install "git+https://github.com/ivanpp/detectron2.git"